# i cant seem to close the form when it exceeded the amount of wrong logins attempt

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i cant seem to close the form  when it exceeded the amount of wrong logins attempt
i would like to know the program to close the form when my wrong login attempts hit above 3 tries

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        string nama = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;


        if (nama.Equals(pass) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login success");
        }
       
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login failed");
            for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login amount exceeded");
                this.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe start by displaying the number of failed login attempts on the form. That will give you a good start to fix your code.

Comment: yeah i could do that but the program keeps looping even after 3 tries

Comment: i would like my program to close when I hit 3 wrong password tries

Comment: Well, then start by actually *counting* your bad password tries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a counter for failed login attempts outside the `button1_click` event; otherwise, your variable will be reinitialized to 0 every time the button is clicked. IN your code you are not even tracking this in a variable, you simply have a for loop. So your code should look something like this:

```
int failedLoginAttemps = 0;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    string nama = textBox1.Text;
    string pass = textBox2.Text;

    //you can instead do this in C#: if (name == pass)
    if (nama.Equals(pass) == true)
    {
        //you probably want to reset the counter if successful
        failedLoginAttempts = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("login success");
    }
   
    else
    {
        //increment the counter here
        failedLoginAttempts ++; 

        MessageBox.Show("login failed");
        if(failedLoginAttempts >= 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login amount exceeded");
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```